# LabVIEW real time XY Graph

Tags: labview

I like the Build XY Graph express VI, because it allows you to add one point at a time and it incrementally plots the new point. However, it allows only one plot in XY graph. If I want to have two or more plots in the same XY graph, is there an equivalent of the Build XY Graph express vi?
Thank you.
Girish Joglekar

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple plots in the XY Graph control. The XY graph accepts an array of plots, just add another plot to it, you can use the same express VI to build another gr[image]aph.

Answer (score 0):

For real time plots I find the [Real/Imaginary Complex Number Function](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview/page/glang/re_im_to_complex.html) handy even when I'm not doing any complex value calculations.  This is because the complex data type holds two floating point values which allows you to update a single plot of an XY Graph with a single complex value because it holds both the X and the Y components of the new data point.  Extending this to multiple plots is done just as Lior explained above (using plots instead of the complex data type) because the XY Graph also accepts an array of complex values where the size of the array corresponds to the number of plots in the XY Graph.  See the function labeled "Re/Im To Complex" in the image/snippet below.  This particular snippet starts overwriting data previously plotted after the first 250 lines have been drawn.  In other words, the line from point 0 to point 1 disappears and is replaced by a new line from point 249 to point 250 and so on.

[image]